# Rollover Image Media with Servoy

Tags: javascript, image, frameworks, media

I am trying to code a rollover Image Media in Servoy. Could someone please help me out with the syntax. I cant use the Design Editor as the form is built in the code.

If this code shows the image:

```
globals.AddButton(v_form,v_action,10,'addRecord.png','Add New Record');
```

how do I amend it to show 'addRecord_ro.png' when i hover with the mouse?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS style sheet to your application using WebClientUtils:

```
plugins.WebClientUtils.addCssReference('http://yourserver.com/css/yourstyle.css')
```

In that style sheet create a css class along the lines of:

```
.my-button:hover { background-image: url(myImage_folder/myImage.png); }
```

Then when show a form, assign the my-button style to your buttons:

```
plugins.WebClientUtils.setExtraCssClass(elements.btn_find, 'my-button');
```

Note: That you are only able to do this in *Web Client* since *Smart Client* does not support the :hover event.

References:

https://servoy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19403 - changing the background color of a button on :hover in Servoy

[https://www.servoy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=14338&p=75767&hilit=image+file+relative+path](https://www.servoy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=14338&p=75767&hilit=image%20file%20relative%20path) - using a relative path for a CSS rollover image in Servoy